# What is the best way to create lists dynamically in Python?

Tags: python, dynamic

My users will be creating an arbitrary number of Human objects and grouping them in as many groups as they like. (The number of groups created will be tracked) I want to create a list for each group that they've created to use later. How can I create a list for each group if I don't know how many groups there will be?

I've thought of something like the following:

```
for i in range(num_groups):
    eval('group_' + str(i) + ' = []')
```

which should create an empty list for group i named group_i. I've read that eval is not something that should be used in most cases, so I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: Are you aware lists of lists are a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a dictionary of lists, so that each name in the form of "group_i" will hold a new list inside that dictionary ("group_i" being the key). If you want to get all lists, you can just have all keys and find corresponding values to reach particular list.

Decleration will be as the following

```
all_groups = {}
for i in range(num_groups):
    new_group_name = "group_" + str(i)
    all_groups[new_group_name] = []
```

In order to add item to a particular group

```
all_groups[group_name].append(item)
```

And you can reach all group names by reaching all keys of dictionary

```
all_groups.keys()
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about

```
groups = [[] for i in range(num_groups)]
```

instead of

```
for i in range(num_groups):
    eval('group_' + str(i) + ' = []')
```

That way you declare `num_groups` lists.

Comment: I don't know how I would access each list, according to it's number.

Comment: @JerAnsel By calling `groups[i]` where `i` is it's number.

Comment: I tried that and received an error: generator object is not subscriptable. The accepted answer works for me though, thanks anyways!

Comment: @JerAnsel Yeah, unlucky :) I've fixed the code though just in case anyone uses this.